# Why is alert in microAjax not outputting text echoed from php file?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to get a string from a text file. I have a php file called genjsonGPS.php that looks like this:

```
<?php

$myFile = "vesselGPS.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$vesselGPS = fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
fclose($fh);

echo("Hello");


?>
```

When I run it, I get for an output in my browser:

"Hello"

I have a webpage with a js file using microAjax (from the js file):

```
microAjax("genjsonGPS.php", function (res) {
  alert (res);
});
```

When I run the webpage I get a blank alert. When I change the function above to:

```
microAjax("genjsonGPS.php", function (res) {
  alert (res.toString);
});
```

I get an alert that says:
     function toString() { [native code] }

How do I get the function above to output "Hello" in the alert like the browser does?

Comment: Do the two functions have any difference?

Comment: Hi, yes I added the toString to the second function just now

Comment: It should be `res.toString()`, I think.

Comment: probably, but in that case I just get the same output I get with the first function. seems microAjax is not accessing genjsonGPS.php for some reason.

Comment: Cannot reproduce error with PHP 5.3.10 / Firefox14. Is microajax sourced like <script type="text/javascript" src="PATH/TO/microajax.minified.js"></script> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow these tips.

- Monitor your HTTP server's access log, something like `tail -f /var/log/apache/access.log` is helpful. (Assume you are working on *nix platform)
- If you are using Chrome, please check out the `network` monitor panel.

You'd better make sure that:

- Your php page is truly accessed.
- There is no error occurs, both in server and client sides.

If you still cannot figure out where things goes wrong, if would be useful to let people know how `microAjax` is implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I am not quite sure what was going on server side. I tried the page again, and then the alert output what I was looking for. Something to do with the cache of files on the server? Anyway, the above was helpful to see more of what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you put the URL like `"/genjsonGPS.php"`?